# How to use keras recall for multi label segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I am using UNet for a segmentation task. The problem I have is that I'm trying to use recall metric and I have 4 labels and I don't know how to make it work for more that 2 labels. Also the input of my nework has the shape (..., 496, 512, 1) and the output (..., 496, 512, 4).

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:759 train_step
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:409 update_state
    metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:176 update_state_fn
    return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:1410 update_state  **
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:353 update_confusion_matrix_variables
    y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

ValueError: Shapes (None, 496, 512, 4) and (None, 496, 512, 1) are incompatible
```

```
def conv2d_block(input_tensor, n_filters, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = True):
    """Function to add 2 convolutional layers with the parameters passed to it"""
    # first layer
    x = Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = (kernel_size, kernel_size),\
              kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(input_tensor)
    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    
    # second layer
    x = Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = (kernel_size, kernel_size),\
              kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(input_tensor)
    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    
    return x

def get_unet(input_img, n_filters = 16, dropout = 0.1, batchnorm = True):
    """Function to define the UNET Model"""
    # Contracting Path
    c1 = conv2d_block(input_img, n_filters * 1, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
    p1 = Dropout(dropout)(p1)
    
    c2 = conv2d_block(p1, n_filters * 2, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
    p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)
    
    c3 = conv2d_block(p2, n_filters * 4, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
    p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)
    
    c4 = conv2d_block(p3, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c4)
    p4 = Dropout(dropout)(p4)
    
    c5 = conv2d_block(p4, n_filters = n_filters * 16, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    
    # Expansive Path
    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    
    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
    c7 = conv2d_block(u7, n_filters * 4, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    
    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    u8 = Dropout(dropout)(u8)
    c8 = conv2d_block(u8, n_filters * 2, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    
    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
    u9 = Dropout(dropout)(u9)
    c9 = conv2d_block(u9, n_filters * 1, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
    
    outputs = Conv2D(4, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
       
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
    return model

input_img = Input((im_height, im_width, 1), name='img')
model = get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.05, batchnorm=True)
recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy", recall])
```

I tried using class_id attribute for recall but I found that it is for binary metrics.

Comment: Please can you include the code you are running?

Comment: I added some parts of the code. I am pretty new to this and what I found on keras metrics seems to be for binary metrics. I don't know where I should look for multi-label metrics documentation. Thank you!